# Storage size isn't known

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
const int MAXWIDTH = 512;
const int MAXHEIGHT = 512;

void readImage(int image[][MAXHEIGHT], int &width, int &height)

....

void writeImage(int image[][MAXHEIGHT], int width, int height)

....

int main ()
{
 int image[][MAXHEIGHT], width, height;

 readImage (image, &width, &height);
 writeImage (image, width, height);
 return 0;
}
```

I keep getting "storage size of "image" isn't known" in the main function and not sure why.

Comment: You cannot have an array that the compiler does not know how big it is.  `int image[][]` only has one dimension defined, which would be fine if you gave it a bunch of brace initializers, but because you did not you need a number in the decleration.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do `int image[][MAXHEIGHT];` when declaring your array unless you are using an initializer list. i.e

```
int image[][5]={ {1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10} };//is OK and the compiler get the row size from your initializer list and creates image[2][5]

int image[][5];//this is not OK because the compiler can't know the size of the row when creating the arrray

int image[MAXWIDTH][MAXHEIGHT];//OK because you specified both dimensions
```

When specifying a formal parameter of a function, you can leave the row dimension of a two dimensional array.i.e

```
void somefunction(image[][MAXWIDTH])//is OK
```

Comment: How would I fix this without changing the protocol because prof required us to use       void readImage(int image[][MAXHEIGHT], int &width, int &height) and       void writeImage(int image[][MAXHEIGHT], int width, int height). Sorry not sure how to format the code in comments.

Comment: @H.C You don't have to change that, just need to change the declaration in main from *int image[][MAXHEIGHT]* to *int image[MAXWIDTH][MAXHEIGHT]*

Comment: I get "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’" on "&height" when I changed it to int image[MAXWIDTH][MAXHEIGHT].

Comment: when calling it, this *readImage (image, &width, &height);* should be *readImage (image, width, height);* because you are passing a reference and not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now, I was stuck on this for a while.